# Javascript: How to destroy the value a group of variables point to?

Tags: javascript, pointers, memory-leaks

So I know how to delete one variable... variable = null; or delete variable; but say I have lots of different variables that all point to the same value but I can only access a few of those variables, how can I clear that value of memory.

So how bout an example... I have:

```
var a = {value:5};    //create the reference everything points to
var b = a;
var c = a;

CallFunctionThatKeepsReference(a);
//var x = a;          //x in this function but I can't directly access x.

a = null; b = null; c = null;    //the object still exists in x.
delete a; delete b; delete c;    //the object still exists in x.

//What can I do to accomplish this effect...
Nuke(a);  //or b, or c
//a,b,c,x now all point to null.
```

I can't access x because it is kept in a function that I call. This is because it is a giant closure and runs async setTimeout code so it never uncloses.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `delete` only works on object properties. Plus, memory management is usually left up to the garbage collector, you don't really have that high a degree of control.

Comment: you can delete a variable, it just sets it equal to 'undefined.' But if another variable pointed to the same value in memory, the memory is not deleted.

Comment: No, you can't delete a var like `a`, `b` or `c`. You could delete `a.value`, but that's because it's an object property. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention this is in the global context. So yeah, in functions delete won't work for variables, but in global it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend another approach at this.  JavaScript isn't C, so you don't need to absolutely and explicitly reclaim all of your own memory.  Instead, write your code so that it works well with the garbage collector.  Specifically, ensure that your variables are declared within functions / closures, at the lowest-level possible for what you need to accomplish.  Once the function finishes, any variables and memory will automatically be recycled.

Comment: This is just the side effect I have from using a function that keeps the reference I pass to it. So I can never make the function release it unless I just do it myself.

Comment: The function you're calling is making a copy of something you pass-in and keeping it persistently someplace else?  (I.E., it's not going out-of-scope once that other function completes?)  Otherwise, there's not much you'll be able to do here, short of getting that other function fixed - unless you have access to wherever the other function is storing its copies.  Additionally, are you sure that attempting such an effort won't cause unintended issues with the functionality provided by that other function?  A more complete code example would also be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes that is essentially the case. I know that a surprise null in the function would be ok but if there is nothing that would solve the issue, I guess I have to move things around to fix this. Thanks for the feedback.